# Polynomials - using Newton's method, or not?

Tags: complexity-theory, floating-point, polynomials

I have to find a root of polynomial of degree $n\ge2$. I need to write code to calculate the root for different values of $n$. Only 1 real positive solution is needed.

I can use general Newton's method for all degrees, or only for 5th+, and for 2,3 and 4 I can use algebraic formulas that solve quadratic, cubic and quartic equations. Since algebraic formulas need to use sqrt, acos and similar functions - does it make sense at all to use algebraic formulas - or is it better to use Newton's method for all degrees? I guess the latter will actually be faster?

This is my equation:

$$\frac{1}{(b_1x + 1)} + \frac{1}{(b_2x + 1)} + ... + \frac{1}{(b_nx + 1)} -k = 0$$

and constraints:

$$1 \leq k<n \\ b_n>0 $$

e.g. for $n=3$:

$$b_1 b_2 b_3 (-k)x^3 +\left(b_1 b_2+b_3 b_2+b_1 b_3- b_1 b_2 k-b_3 b_2 k-b_1 b_3 k\right)x^2 + \left(2 b_1+2 b_2+2
   b_3-b_1 k-b_2 k-b_3 k\right)x + 3-k =0$$

which can be written as

$$\sum_{i=0}^n(n-i-k)\binom{\{b_1,...,b_n\}}{i}x^i=0.$$

Comment: Is the question how to find the roots of a polynomial the fastest?

Comment: Yes - is it faster to use Newton's method for 2nd, 3rd and 4th degree polynomial or is it faster to use quadratic, cubic and quartic equations?

Comment: @Apass.Jack I updated equation to be equal to 0

Comment: These are all integral polynomials, might be counting something, it possible you have rational roots in which case use the rational roots theorem and be done precisely and quickly.

Comment: @Algeboy I need only one positive real solution. I will update question.

Comment: Are you writing a library? Even in that case, can you reuse some existing library that finds the roots of polynomials?

Comment: just as you can see it from second equation above, it is polynomial of nth degree.

Comment: hopefully better now.

Answer (score 1):

The sum goes to infinity at x = -1 / $b_i$. Between $b_i$ and $b_{I+1}$ it is continuous. So each of these intervals contains a point wher the sum of fractions equals k. Go from there.

Comment: Thanks. I guess this is initial guess for newtons method? I just updated constraints for variables in equations - does it change anything? Also, do you recommend Newton's method for all or only n>=5 ?